# Toggle the background div while keep the frnt div stable jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, css-position

I have one container in my html, and this one has a box as a background div and one second div on top of this.

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
 </div>
```

I want to click div1 and then div2 will toggle, but I want div1 to stay in the same position. What happens in my case, is that while the animation is happening I can see the div2 moving below.
If I use position absolute then it works. But is there a way to do that without position absolute? Here is the css I am using now.

```
 #container{
    position: relative;
 }

 #div1, #div2{
   position: absolute;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your js code??? please make fiddle if thats possible.

Comment: if you could add a fiddle that would be great

Comment: Ok here is an example. http://jsfiddle.net/8M6Bs/1/

Comment: That example works. The preferred fiddle would be the one that doesn't work like you expect.

Comment: Ok I change it to one, that works as I do not like. So now in order to place the div2 in the right position I have to use negative margin. and when I toggle it the div2 moves down. So is it possible to have the previous result but without using position absolute?
The new fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/8M6Bs/2/

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/8M6Bs/3/?

Comment: @j08691 It seems that is the desired output, but without using `position: absolute;` for whatever reason.

Comment: ok as long as we cannot avoid position absolute, I am ok with it. Thank you